# Какие параметры systemd.serive необходимы для первичной установки PostgreSQL и немедленного запуска?

Tags: postgresql, debian, systemd, pxe

Подготовка сервера разбита на две части

1. Первичная PXE preseed установка чистой ОС (Debian Stretch/Jessie) с добавлением сервиса для `systemd` который должен завершить конфигурацию после перезагрузки.
2. `systemd` сервис стартует bash скрипт, ставящий вереницу недостающих пакетов один из которых `postgresql`, в дальнейшем он добавляет базу данных по шаблону, где и ломается.

При запуске того же скрипта в "ручном режиме" все успешно ставится. Подозрения на то, что `systemd` НЕ стартует `posgresql` сервер, а просто продолжает выполнение установочного сценария.

Пробовал разные типы:

- `Type=simple` ломается конфигурация модулей ядра; сервис виснет на полпути.
- `Type=forking` не стартует база после установки, ломаются зависимости от этого в сценарий

*firstboot.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Postinstall bootstrap
AssertPathExists=/path/to/dir

[Service]
Type=simple # forking
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir
Environment="INSTALL_SETTINGS=full-install"
ExecStart=/path/to/dir/script.sh
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/systemctl disable fistboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Так же пробовал ставить все за один заход в `preseed` не взлетело, в силу того что многие сервисы не стараются.

---

**UPD**

Ключевой момент в том, что установочный скрипт отрабатывает без проблем если запустить его после полной загрузки системы в ручную, и "ломается" на моменте, где создается БД по шаблону из `systemd.service`. Один из шагов - установка `postgresql`, которая НЕ стартует автоматически как при ручной установке.

Задача стоит в том, что бы сконцентрировать сервис `systemd` без сторонних пакетом (`initscripts`) стартующий все сервисы из предоставленного ему установочного сценария.

Изначальная проблема - автоспуск сценариия поставленного после `preseed` стадии PXE установки. На Debian stretch/jessie отсутствует «тёплый ламповый» `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: почему бы не вызвать скрипт из `/etc/rc.local`? в background не забудьте его отправить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `rc.local` не существует в debian stretch/jessie  по умолчанию. Его нужно активировать через сервис, что возращает меня к изначальной проблеме.

Comment: ну, да, пакет initscripts нынче по умолчанию не устанавливается. что не мешает поставить его самостоятельно. и получить в том числе «тёплый ламповый» `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin. это уводит от решения проблемы и создания костыльной затычки -  почему `systemd` не стартует приложение установленное через скрипи запущенный сценарием. Первичная задача сводилась к автозапуску скрипта при первом старте системы перереросла в пляску с бубном вокруг `systemd` на Debian stretch/jessie :)

Comment: ничего не понял. уход от костыльной затычки под названием systemd — это плохо?! ну, если плохо, то разбирайтесь с «в дальнейшем он добавляет базу данных по шаблону, где и ломается». к сожалению, вы про эту проблему ровно одну (процитированную фразу) написали, так что лучше задайте новый вопрос, в который и добавьте существенных деталей про эту самую поломку.

Comment: Возможно ему чего-то не хватает. Я бы смотрел в сторону `After` в блоке `[Unit]`. Например, старт после запуска сети: `[Unit] ... After=network.target`

Comment: Ещё вариант попробовать `Type=idle`. Т.е. выполнение этого задания после завершения всех остальных.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего `systemd` стартует нужный сервис, но не дожидается, пока тот поднимется. Поставьте в установочном скрипте задержку на **~15** секунд.

```
sleep 15;
```

Comment: `ExecStart=/path/to/dir/script.sh` содержит бутсрап установщик различных пакетов один из которых `postgresql` пост установочный скрипт которого НЕ запускает базу после установк (она начинает работает, когда сервис завершает работу) пока не завершен `firstboot.service` в свете этого я не вижу смысла в `sleep` где либо в `/path/to/dir/script.sh`

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению, в силу описанго поведения `systemd` в вопросе и комментарии к вашему ответу.